# Pip install local package give OSError [Errno1]

Tags: python, pip, flit

I am attempting to install a package that I downloaded from GitHub with as `.toml` file.

When I navigate the folder containing the `.toml` and run:

```
$ python -m pip install --user .
```

I get a long string of errors which looks like:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: ["[Errno 1] Operation not permitted ... LONG LIST OF DIRETORIES]
```

I also get this error when calling `sudo pip`. I have given full hard drive access to `terminal`.

I am running python 3.9 on MaxOs 12.0.1 Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the flag `--use-feature=in-tree-build`  got rid of this error.

Explicitly:

```
$ python -m pip install --user . --use-feature=in-tree-build
```